# Install as a Website not a Virtual Directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, web-setup-project, iis-8.5

I'm testing migration of websites to a Windows 2012 IIS 8.5. machine and when I create a Web Setup Project in VS2010 I can't find a way to get it to install on IIS 8.5 as a website. It always installs as a Virtual Directory underneath the defaultwebsite.

Is there something I'm missing? Everywhere I've read seems to say a web setup project installs things as a virtual directory. Is there no option anywhere to install as a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so simple I could kick myself...

Simply setup the website definition in IIS, then when you run the installer, in the section Select Installation Address, select the website in the top field, then blank out the virtual directory field.

This causes the installer to install without creating a virtual directory!